# converting numbers into alphabets

Tags: javascript

I want to convert numbers into alpha characters using JavaScript.  For example, 01=n, 02=i 03=n, 04=a, etc.

When someone enters the numbers:01020304 in the form he will get the response: nina.  Whatever the user enters gets replaced with the equivalent characters including spaces.

#### Update

Thank you all for quick response. I have found this code in one site.  It converts alpha characters into numbers, but code for converting numbers into alpha characters isn't working. Here is the code for converting alpha characters into numbers:

```
var i,j;
var getc;
var len;
var num, alpha;

num=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17",
"18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","00","##","$$");

alpha=new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","
v","w","x","y","z"," ",".",",");

function encode() {
  len=document.f1.ta1.value.length;
  document.f1.ta2.value="";
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    getc=document.f1.ta1.value.charAt(i);
    getc=getc.toLowerCase();
    for(j=0;j<alpha.length;j++) {
      if(alpha[j]==getc) {
        document.f1.ta2.value+=num[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone show me how to convert this to do the opposite character conversion?

Comment: No, that's not how this works. We can help you if you come across any particular problems, but you need to learn to do it yourself.

Comment: You have to provide the list of translations you are looking for.

Comment: I second Cybernate's motion, this does not seem to have any type of discernable logic associated with it as far as 01020304 returning nina.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Skrilldrick, you should learn how to do this yourself, but I couldn't help myself: http://jsfiddle.net/dQkxw/

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="code">
        <button onclick="decode($('#code').val())">
            Decode
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.decode = function(numbers) {
    if (numbers.length % 2 != 0)
    {
        alert("invalid code!");
        return;
    }

    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i+=2) {
        var number = Number(numbers.substring(i, i+2));
        if (number < 1 || number > 26)
        {
            alert("invalid number: "+number);
            return;
        }

        result += String.fromCharCode(96+number);
    }

    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this easily, and so it is a scalable solution would be to have a multi dimensional array that maps each char to it's corresponding char.  You can have multiple dimensions for each conversion and pick between them.

```
var myCharArray=new Array(4)
for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
myCharArray[i]=new Array(2)

myCharArray[0][0]="a"
myCharArray[0][1]="1"
myCharArray[1][0]="b"
myCharArray[1][1]="2"
myCharArray[2][0]="c"
myCharArray[2][1]="3"
myCharArray[3][0]="d"
myCharArray[3][1]="4"
```

Then, upon conversion, loop every single character in your string to be encoded, and search for it in the array.  If it is found, switch it with the encoded value.  This should be reasonably easy to do.

The method you described seems to be a simple derivative off a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  Also remember because the script is client side, it will be incredible easy to decode, so make sure it's not for anything important!